# Macro having structure with parentheses

Tags: c, macros, struct

I just found somewhere a code like :

```
#include"stdio.h"

typedef struct st
{
  int num;
  char c;
  int abc;
} Str, *pStr;

#define MyStr(Dcn) Str(Dcn)

int main()
{
  Str Str1;
  MyStr(Dcn);
  return 0;
}
```

Please tell what the #define line means here? As it is not giving any compilation problem. So if I use `#define` something to a "structure with parentheses" then what happens?

Here `Dcn` can be anything not with quotes. When I used a number instead it showed compilation error.

Comment: What's Dcn? Also are you sure this is C? It looks like it's using a C++ constructor.

Comment: Dcn is nothing but anything without quotes.

Comment: Nothing but anything?

Comment: As I saw when I changed it to a number it was not working and when I changed it to a unquoted string then it worked.

Comment: Hm, well someone said it just declares a variable named Dcn, so it can't include characters that aren't allowed in variable names.

Answer (score 4):

This defines an alias for `Str`. It is equivalent to

```
int main()
{
    Str Str1;
    Str(Dcn);
    return 0;
}
```

Which simply declares a variable `Dcn` of type `Str`.

Comment: So,anything I write within parentheses of a structure becomes a variable of structure type?

Comment: Anything you write within parentheses of the *macro* becomes a variable of structure type `Str`

Answer (score 0):

It's a function-like macro, it's expanded to the right-hand side with the arguments replaced.

A classical example is this, to compute max of two values:

```
#define MAX(a, b)    ((a) > (b) ? a : b)
```

You can use it like this:

```
int hello = 12, there = 47;
int what = MAX(hello, there);
```

The second line will expand to:

```
int what = ((12) > (47) ? 12 : 47);
```

In other words, `what` will be `47`. Note that this macro evaluates its arguments more than once, which can be harmful if there are side-effects.

As of C99, you can also do [variadic preprocessor macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.0/gcc/Variadic-Macros.html#Variadic-Macros).

The code you're showing will expand to:

```
Str Str1;
Str(Dcn);  /* This is the macro-expansion. */
```

Comment: Why won't it compile? It looks like the `()` are redundant and it will be seen as equivalent to `Str Dcn;`, isn't it?

Comment: @PaulR Thanks, I removed that bit.